# sencha touch 2pr4 - xtype: passwordfield property for numbers only

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, validation, sencha-touch-2

in sencha touch 2pr4, 
is it possible to set some property for **input (xtype:passwordfield) that will accept numbers only same as (xtype:numberfield)** ?

so it wont bring keypad set to alpha-characters everytime you have to fill i.e. PIN field

**example input**

```
    {
xtype: 'fieldset',
defaults: {
    margin: '0 3 0 3'
    },
layout: 'hbox',
items: [
    {
    xtype: 'passwordfield', 
    maxLength: 1,
    name : 'pin1',
    useClearIcon: false,
    autoCapitalize : false,
    flex: 1,
    index: 1
    }]
}
```

**modify sencha-touch.js ?**

```
Ext.define('Ext.field.Password', {
    extend: 'Ext.field.Text',
    alias : 'widget.passwordfield',
    alternateClassName: 'Ext.form.Password',

    config: {
        // @inherit
        autoCapitalize: false,

        // @inherit
        component: {
            type: 'password' // is there alternative ? 

              // changing field onFocus to type:number and back to star* character ?
        }
    }});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can extend a normal text or pass field and get the number keyboard, take a look at this solution provided on the sencha forum: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?152639-Trigger-number-only-keypad-on-iOS-Android